# What is a root widget and how to implement it in Kivy Python ?

Tags: python, root, kivy

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage 

class WeaselApp(App):

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image 

    def coreimage(self, load_image):
        self.load_image = load_image 
        load_image = CoreImage("psychTREE.jpg") 
        #return load_image 

    def built(self):
        return coreimage(self, load_image)

if __name__== "__main__":
    WeaselApp(App).run()
```

When I run it, it says " WeaselApp has no attribute 'root' ". Why is this the case? Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `def build` instead

Comment: it says " Weasel App has no attribute 'built' " when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return any widget from your build method, for two reasons:

1. As Joran Beasley said, you need a `build` method, not `built`.
2. CoreImage is not a widget that can be displayed on screen, it's a low level tool to load image data. You should use a `kivy.uix.image.Image` widget.

Edit: Following the comments, replace your code with this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Image(source='psychTREE.jpg')

YourApp().run()  # edited this in after
```

Comment: When I use the build method instead, I get " 'HardApp' object has no attribute 'built' ". I don't know why this is the case. Please help.

Comment: This is because you override `__init__` but don't call super. Since your code does nothing, you can just remove this method, or alternatively (if you really want to override it) call the super(...) init.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I posted an update as an answer ! In this update version, the last line of code is returning an error. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: please help . I've gone through all my options.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - why pass App to the HardApp instance, save it in a variable named coreimage, and try to reference it as HardApp().coreimage...all of these things are strange and (together) just wrong? Plus, as in my point number 2, you can't use a CoreImage as the root widget anyway because it's not a widget.

Comment: I'm trying to run a gui with the PsychTREE.jpg image.

Comment: I edited in some example code to do this - you just need to use an Image widget.

Comment: I took your advice and took a more concise approach. Now the problem I am experiencing is the image is not loading into the GUI. All I get is a black screen. I posted the code as an answer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That's because you don't write any code that would display an image. I don't understand why you're doing any of this, what instructions are you following that make you think it will work? Why didn't you just use my example?